# Unable to find Open XML word Table top border element

Tags: c#, ms-word, openxml, openxml-sdk, wordml

I am creating a table in MS Word the table looks like as shown below .

1. [image: Word Table]
2. I then ZIP the file and open the document.xml and check for the border elements in the table grid . this is how it looks . I am checking the for border element that is the top border element.
   [image: Document table contents]
3. All the border are displayed as none . Then i check the **TableGrid** in the **styles.xml** file for table borders below is how the TableGrid styles look like in the styles.xml
   [image]

The problem here is i am not able to find where exactly is the border element getting assigned. The top black line in the table ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Borders can be defined at table level via TableStyle (here `w:tblBorders` in *TableGrid* style) or via `tablesProperties` (here `w:tblBorders` in `w:tblPr`).

If both of them are definied, there is a conflict and borders definied via `tablesProperties` will win.

Since the `w:tblBorders` in `w:tblPr` are set to `None`, there is no borders.

But I noticed that **TopBorder** is missing here (you have Left, Right, Bottom InsideH and InsideV),

It's why, for the TopBorder, *MS Word* is using the `TopBorder` definied in *TableGrid* style and it is set to `Single`.

So, to remove the top border, you have to :

- add the TopBorder which is missing in `w:tblBorders` in `w:tblPr` (and set it to `none` like others)
- **Or** set the borders to `None` in the *TableGrid* style.